# limit number of documents in aggregation elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Query:

```
{
    "fields" : [],
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "top-terms" : {
            "terms": {
                "field" : "content",
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
Array
(
    [took] => 20475
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 5
            [successful] => 5
            [failed] => 0
        )

    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 2652291
            [max_score] => 0
            [hits] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [aggregations] => Array
        (
            [top-terms] => Array
                (
                    [doc_count_error_upper_bound] => 1214666
                    [sum_other_doc_count] => 831757781
                    [buckets] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => the
                                    [doc_count] => 2645615
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => to
                                    [doc_count] => 2638675
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => of
                                    [doc_count] => 2637099
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => and
                                    [doc_count] => 2633262
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => a
                                    [doc_count] => 2625627
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => in
                                    [doc_count] => 2621823
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => for
                                    [doc_count] => 2523026
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => is
                                    [doc_count] => 2480382
                                )

                            [8] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => on
                                    [doc_count] => 2450387
                                )

                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => that
                                    [doc_count] => 2447827
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Aggregation on 2652291 documents ([total] => 2652291)

How can I limit number of documents to 1000?

```
size: 1000
```

does not work

"Ignore this text, i am just adding it here so stackoverflow lets me to post the question."

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding limit filter

```
"filtered": {
    "filter": {
        "limit": {
           "value": 200
        }
    }
}
```

A limit filter limits the number of documents (per shard) to execute on.
More info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/query-dsl-limit-filter.html

Comment: You should have tried to use [`shard_size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_shard_size_2) in your `terms` aggregation as well.